# D3 update bar chart VUE.js

Tags: vue.js, d3.js, methods, bar-chart, data-visualization

Hey I have a problem with d3 chart in Vue. Everything is loading fine except updating data.

I'm using props to pass the data and as the data is changing my chart instead of updating it creates another one just below the current one.

What I wanna do is to keep the current graph and update only the bars as data is changing

```
<script>
export default {
    props: {
      arr: {
          type: Array
      }, 
      colors: {
          type: Array
      }
  },
  watch: {
    arr: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(val) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.barCharts(val)
        }, 100);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    barCharts(data) {
      let margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60 };
      let width = 650
      let height = 240; 

      let color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.colors);
      let t = d3.transition().duration(750);

      let g = d3
        .select("#barChart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", "100%")
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`);

      let xAxisGroup = g
        .append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", `translate(0, ${height})`);

      let yAxisGroup = g.append("g").attr("class", "y axis");

      // X Scale
      let x = d3
        .scaleBand()
        .range([0, width])
        .padding(0.2);

      // Y Scale
      let y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

      // axis
      x.domain(data.map(d => d.name));
      y.domain([
        0,
        d3.max(data, function(d) {
          return d.value;
        })
      ]);

      g.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .selectAll("text")
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("dx", "-.8em")
        .attr("dy", ".15em")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-30)");

      g.append("g")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .attr("class", "axis");

      // draw bars
      let rects = g.selectAll("rect").data(data);

      rects
        .transition(t)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i));

      rects
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.name);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("fill", (d, i) => color(i))
        .attr("y", y(0))
        .attr("height", 0)
        .transition(t)
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });

    }
  }
};
}
</script>
```

Can I implement another function ex. update to call inside of this function to update only the bard??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You generate a new bar graph because you're appending a new SVG element to your target in the `barCharts` method. Every time it's called, it will append a new SVG with the updated data, causing your issue of duplicate charts.

Since Vue has its own means of rendering and updating DOM elements, you shouldn't use d3 to do that, as that messes with Vue reactivity and cleanup (meaning you may end up having memory leaks or elements not being removed).

My advice is to define your `<svg>`, `<g>` and other elements in your vue `<template>`, and use the v-bind directive to pass your bar graph values to the vue-rendered SVG elements. For example you can use the methods from `d3-scale` to create `x`, `y`, and `barColor` methods/computed properties in your component. Then you can bind the results for each bar to the correct properties in the template, for example `<rect v-for="(bar, index) in bars" :x="x(bar.name)" :y="y(bar.value)" :width="x.bandwidth()" :height="height - y(bar.value)" :fill="barColor(index)" />` or similar.

Let me know if this is sufficient for you to get on your way, otherwise I'll be able to write you a full example later today. I also recommend these videos on combining vue and d3, which were very insightful for me:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=30v9xnB-GEo
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CkFktv0p3pw

Comment: great! thanks a lot! I will try to use the videos in case of any troubles I will let you know! :)

Comment: Hi @Excalibaard  I posted below approach according your suggestion. Is working perfectly just have one doubt about transitions. If you have a min would you take a look at that?

Answer (score 2):

I've changed that according to your suggestion and I can admit it's brilliant!! It's working perfectly just have one issue with transition. I'm not quite sure where I should place that... On enter I want to make transition y from 0 to the height of the bar and then make another transition when the data changes.

I would appreciate your help again!

```
<template>
  <svg class="barChart" :width="width" height="340">
    <g>
    <!-- axis bottom -->
       <g class="x-axis" fill="none" :transform="`translate(0, ${height})`">
        <path stroke="currentColor" :d="`M0.5,6V0.5H${width}.5V6`"></path>
        <g
          class="tick"
          opacity="1"
          font-size="10"
          font-family="sans-serif"
          text-anchor="middle"
          v-for="(bar, index) in bars"
          :key="index"
          :transform="`translate(${bar.x + bar.width / 2}, 0)`"
        >
          <line stroke="currentColor" y2="6"></line>
          <text fill="currentColor" y="9" dy="0.71em">{{ bar.xLabel }}</text>
        </g>
      </g>

      <!-- y-axis -->
      <g class="y-axis" fill="none" :transform="`translate(0, 0)`">
        <path
          class="domain"
          stroke="currentColor"
          :d="`M0.5,${height}.5H0.5V0.5H-6`"
        ></path>
        <g
          class="tick"
          opacity="1"  
          font-size="10"
          font-family="sans-serif"
          text-anchor="end"
          v-for="(tick, index) in yTicks"
          :key="index"
          :transform="`translate(0, ${y(tick) + 0.5})`"
        >
          <line stroke="currentColor" x2="-6"></line>
          <text fill="currentColor" x="-9" dy="0.32em">{{ tick }}</text>
        </g>
      </g>
      <!-- bars -->
      <g class="bars" fill="none">
        <rect 
          v-for="(bar, index) in bars"
          :fill="color(bar.xLabel)"
          :key="index"
          :height="bar.height"
          :width="bar.width"
          :x="bar.x"
          :y="bar.y"
        ></rect>
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</template>
<script>
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { scaleBand, scaleLinear } from 'd3-scale'
export default { 
  props: {
    dataset: {
      type: Array
    }, 
    colors: {
      type: Array
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      height: 240,
      width: 650
    }
  },
  computed: {
    color() {
      return d3.scaleOrdinal().range(this.colors); 
    },
    yTicks() {
      return this.y.ticks(5);
    },
    x() {
      return scaleBand()
      .range([0, this.width])
      .padding(0.3)
      .domain(this.dataset.map(e => e[0]));
    },

    y() {
      let values = this.dataset.map(e => e[1]);
      return scaleLinear()
      .range([this.height, 0])
      .domain([0, Math.max(...values)]);
    },
    bars() {
      let bars = this.dataset.map(d => {
        return {
          xLabel: d[0],
          x: this.x(d[0]),
          y: this.y(d[1]),
          width: this.x.bandwidth(),
          height: this.height - this.y(d[1])
        };
      });
      return bars;
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Should it be in a watch?? Or maybe somewhere in computed?? Or should I create a method to call the transitions?

Comment: You can do this two ways. You can cache the data and calculate the datapoints between your cached and new state (so 0 to data, or data to newData) using JS (animation libraries), but my preferred method is using CSS transitions. Add a class to your `<rect>` and define transitions for each attribute you want to have an animated transition, so `.barAnimation { transition: height 0.5s ease, fill 1s ease-in;` for example. You may need to set an initial 'dataset' you want to transition from in the created hook to get proper animation from 0.

Comment: Quick sidenote: if you're importing everything from d3, you don't need to separately import methods from d3-scale, just access the d3 object. An optimization later down the line could be to customize your own d3 bundle with parts from d3-scale and others that you use in order to have a smaller bundle size in webpack.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! It's working perfectly. I really appreciate your help ! Thanks a lot!